# How to support email subscriptions to many rss feeds

Tags: email, rss

I am interested in having the option to be able to subscribe to any of my RSS feeds by email, without having to manage any of the email lists.

Are there any email delivery services that allow easy subscription to arbitrary feeds? [MailChimp's api doesn't allow list creation](http://getsatisfaction.com/mailchimp/topics/mailchimp_api_doesnt_allow_list_creation).

The closest I can come up with is linking people to a google alert:

```
http://www.google.com/alerts?q=site:mysite.com/category/food
http://www.google.com/alerts?q=site:mysite.com/category/drinks
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I assume you want people to be able to subscribe to your RSS via email?

If so, check out [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com/). They have email subscription support that I have been using for many of my blogs.

Comment: With Feedburner you need to manage the feeds manually (i.e. "burn a feed") before someone can subscribe to it by email. I'm looking to be able to let someone get emails from a feed without having to manually create an email list for it.

Comment: Burning a feed is pretty easy though, and once you have it set up you can pretty much forget about it. No need to manage lists. (Apologies if I am completely misunderstanding you.)